# What is a good, authoritative source on the history of Tibet?

Tags: sources, asia, tibet

I'd like to know more about this topic as people often discuss it with me. What is a good book for me to read to gain a better understanding of Tibetan history?

Comment: *The Great Game: On Secret Service in High Asia* and *Trespassers on the Roof of the World: The Race for Lhasa* by Peter Hopkirk have  large sections on Tibetan history during the 19th century. Younghusband's books may help you as well if you are looking for a primary source.

Comment: Thanks for that - will check them out. I'm hoping for a more overarching view, but they should provide some good reading as well.

Comment: There maybe something more in the reference sections.  The lack of overarching view is why it is a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using my elite Amazon search skills, I discovered [Tibet: A History](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0300154046) by Sam van Schaik, which looks like what you want.

Personally, I'm a fan of reading literature and/or biographies, as I find concrete stories give me a better handle on the more abstract cultural or political issues covered in a regular history.  Sardathrion's books look interesting, as does [Tibetan Diary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0300154046) by Geoff Childs.

Comment: That looks pretty interesting - thanks a bunch.